# Php weird calculation with for. Restarts every time

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, row, element

My idea was to create a row with divs. With all of them given the number of their place in the row. Now I've got this problem and I dont know how to fix it..

I got this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){

    $elementNumber = "Rownumber: " . $i;
    $element = $dom->createElement('div', $elementNumber);
    $dom->appendChild($element);

    echo $dom->saveXML();
}
?>
```

That puts out:

```
Rownumber: 1
Rownumber: 1
Rownumber: 2
Rownumber: 1
Rownumber: 2
Rownumber: 3
Rownumber: 1
Rownumber: 2
Rownumber: 3
Rownumber: 4
```

but I just want this:

```
Rownumber: 1
Rownumber: 2
Rownumber: 3
Rownumber: 4
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `echo $dom->saveXML();` to the outside of the loop.

saveXML, without any arguments prints the entirety of the data held in $dom;

Comment: Damn.. that was easy.. I feel like such a noob now haha thanks!